# Connect to SQL Server 2008 on web server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a ASP.NET application which is in a web server. I want my application to connect to SQL Server which is in my local machine. How is it done using TCP/IP. I tried specifying the IP address of my local machine in the Server section and added the exception in the firewall etc. But I am getting error all the time.

***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)***

Comment: Impossible to answer this question.  What is the error?

Comment: I believe this is more appropriate for serverfault.com

Comment: did you enabled the TCP protocol in Sql Server Service Configuration tools ?

Comment: named pipe is also cool : \\.\pipe\MSSQL\sql\query...

Comment: i tried all these steps... no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The IP of your local machine has to be a static IP
2. On firewalls of WebServer and your local machine add exceptions to PORT 1433, 1434 both incoming and outgoing
3. Ensure that you have correct Username and password

Comment: hmm... I am not really sure if a system can be hooked to two networks simultaneously. If your webserver is a production server, then that may be risky. If not then, you can have both the machines on a vpn and then you can access your local system via system name from the connection string that you are having in your webserver.
But still you will need to open ports at both machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post your connection string might help, but make sure it has Network Library=DBMSSOCN in it and "Data Source=your ip here,1433".

I believe port 1433 is the default for SQL Server.